# How to combine values from three different fields and set it to the hidden field only when all the three fields are filled with values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, string-concatenation, hidden-field

I've six fields on a form for showing the start time and end time in **Hour: Minutes AM/PM** format as follows :

```
                    <div class="block-time-term" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                      <label>Starts at :</label>
                      <select name="hours_start" id="hours_start">
                        <option value="">hh</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                      </select>
                      <select name="minutes_start" id="minutes_start">
                        <option value="">mm</option>
                        <option value="0">00</option>
                        <option value="5">05</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="35">35</option>
                        <option value="40">40</option>
                        <option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="55">55</option>
                      </select>
                      <select name="am_pm_start" id="am_pm_start">
                        <option value="AM">AM</option>
                        <option value="PM">PM</option>        
                      </select>
                      <br><br>
                      <label>Ends at :</label>
                      <select name="hours_end" id="hours_end">
                        <option value="">hh</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                      </select>
                      <select name="minutes_end" id="minutes_end">
                        <option value="">mm</option>
                        <option value="0">00</option>
                        <option value="5">05</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="35">35</option>
                        <option value="40">40</option>
                        <option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="55">55</option>
                      </select>
                      <select name="am_pm_end" id="am_pm_end">
                        <option value="AM">AM</option>
                        <option value="PM">PM</option>        
                      </select>
                      </div>
```

Now there are two hidden fields present on the form as follows :

```
<input type="hidden" name="val[start_time]" id="start_time" value=""/>      
<input type="hidden" name="val[end_time]" id="end_time" value=""/>
```

Now what I want to do is when user selects all the values from the respective drop downs only then the selected values should get combined and should be stored in respecive hidden fields.

For example if user selects Start Time as follows 2 from Hour, 30 from Minutes and PM then the string to be formed and to be stored should be `02:35 PM`. Same should be applicable to end date.

If anything is missing proper alert message should appear. How should I achieve this using jQuery/Javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a JSFiddle for you. I made the hidden text boxes visible for you to check the output. It's better to replace the `alert` messages with a `DIV` in production. Hope this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/su8898/m5r140cy/4/

Comment: Thanks for your help but the ned date is not getting set in to the field.

Comment: Provide me the new fiddle link.